# Adjust the column width only when its content cant fit in

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have form with DataGridView on it that displays data. Everything looks fine except when one of the columns content is wider then the column width. So I searched and found a line of code that I added to my Adjust_the DGV_width method so that columns width is adjusted

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in zGrid1.Columns)
{
    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```

It works nicely but it is ugly and I would prefer to keep the columns width as is except when there is content that cant fit in. 
How can I programmaticaly find out what is the width of the content that cant fit columns width?
Here is how it looks now, but I prefer when there is more space in columns.

[image: The form]

Comment: What do you want? The method specified already scales the columns by cell size. What is ugly about it you think a bit of code can do better

Comment: I already said what I want, I want to keep the column width at 100(default) except when content cant fit in.

Comment: You don't have to autosize for each column, you can do it for the whole table like in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by checking the column width after setting it to autosize.

**Example:**

```
int myDefaultWidth = 100;
myDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
foreach ( DataGridViewColumn column in myDataGridView.Columns )
{
    if ( column.Width < myDefaultWidth)
    {
        column.Width = myDefaultWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: I adjusted your code to work with mine, but I had to turn the AutoSizeColumnsMode to None to make it work, but anyways it works. Thanks!